# Setting BIND up with multiple domains and subdomains?

Tags: domain, subdomain, bind, vps

I was wondering if anybody has, or knows of a full tutorial for setting up domains on a server(VPS specifically)?

I need to be able to run multiple domains on it and have sub domains.

Thanks in advance for any help, I already have BIND installed but don't know how to configure it properly.

Answer (score 0):

too many ways to skin this cat, but if you dont know the basics of server administration, i would get a shared webhosting package or get a pro to set your server up, too many things could get done wrong otherwise and leave you open to security risks or similar issues

otherwise, your probably wouldnt go far wrong from installing cpanel on your vps to do the "setup" for you